# How to create a slider without an outline?

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider, sprite

I want to create a slider without an outline.

Like this one:

[image: Slider without outline with curly edges]

Note rounded edges.

I assume I need to create a sprite for that. Unfortunately, I can't find any good tutorials on sprites for sliders. I think the easiest way would be to edit the built-in one but I don't know how to get it for editing.

This is how the original slider from my Unity looks like:

[image: Original slider from my Unity]

Note the outline.

Comment: Am I missing something? The sliders in my Unity literally look like the picture of the one you just posted.

Comment: The original one has the outline. Look at the picture I just posted.

Comment: Yup you're right, I had it on a background that totally blocked it off. Let me see if there is something I can figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, surprising solution that should be available to all of us.

Put the default slider in and go to the `Source Image` for both the `Background` and `Handle`. Instead of using what is there, change it to another Unity Standard sprite called `TouchpadSprite`. This should do the trick. Not sure if the fact that this is called 'touchpad'sprite will cause a problem when make a PC game, but I doubt it. FYI the [TouchpadSprite](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2017-3-32351#content) is from the "Standard Assets (for Unity 2017.3)" that is available for free in the [Unity Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/). Feel free to only import the sprite itself. The Asset Pack itself is pretty large, but there is a lot of good/useful stuff in there.

Also, you will have to increase the `Pixels Per Unit Multiplier` value. My picture shows what I had to increase it to. This will allow you to choose the rounding of your edges as well. Play with it and let me know if it works.

Hope this helps!

[image: Example]

Comment: I don't have the sprite called `TouchpadSprite`. https://imgur.com/a/hMfCagW Do I need to import something extra? My Unity version: 2019.3.3f1 (7ceaae5f7503). I have only 7 built-in Unity sprites to choose from. https://imgur.com/hQohpaO

Comment: @Defozo So I really thought this was either standard with Unity or downloadable via the free 'Standard Assets (for Unity 2017.3)' found in the Asset Store. Let me look around some more. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Defozo Found it. Download the Standard Assets pack from Unity here: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2017-3-32351#content. You can either find it in there and download the sprite specifically, or you can just snag the whole thing. There's a lot of useful stuff in there, but it is a pretty heavy Asset Pack. I've also, updated my answer to contain the link. I hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, there is no TouchpadSprite and setting the background to None simply sets the background color behind it, I still want it to be transparent behind, just with no black border. EDIT: removing ui sprite from fillarea > fill works, although it removes the rounded corners too